# Part of LAN unreachable through access point

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have the following situation:

- ISP modem which is also router + wireless
- Bunch of devices connected to router (wired and wireless)
- An access point which serves as client
- my desktop PC connected (wired) to the access point

The desktop PC (wired connection to AP => router):
- has access to internet.
- can ping my router (192.168.1.1)
- can ping a raspberry pi (wired connection to router) 
- can NOT ping my NAS (also wired connection to router)

The I have my laptop, which is just another client on the network, but does NOT have to go through the access point (as it connects directly to the wireless router) and can ping every device in my LAN, including the AP, and the desktop PC.

When I run advanced IP scanner on my laptop it lists all devices in my LAN. When I run advanced IP scanner on my desktop it does not list all devices. But it does list a few devices which are connected to the router (wired and wireless).

[image: NAS and OPENELEC are missing on desktop scan]

IPConfig /all Desktop PC

```
C:\Users\baspr>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC-BAS
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 6C-62-6D-3C-08-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:a456:26ec:1:85c4:14ab:8a77:7209(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:a456:26ec:1:c80:6c16:b4eb:c767(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::85c4:14ab:8a77:7209%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.17(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, May 30, 2018 10:10:35 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 31, 2018 10:10:37 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::7e39:53ff:fec1:1b36%8
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 40657517
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-14-D0-52-6C-62-6D-3C-08-17
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::7e39:53ff:fec1:1b36%8
                                       195.121.1.34
                                       195.121.1.66
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

IPConfig /all Laptop:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : JAV14941
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : IAI.nl
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : IAI.nl
                                       home

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-8A-60-A6-01-D0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:a456:26ec:1:c15f:43b4:d1b:330a(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:a456:26ec:1:56b:56a3:802e:48f5(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c15f:43b4:d1b:330a%19(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.117(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 31 May 2018 15:10:45
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 01 June 2018 15:10:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::7e39:53ff:fec1:1b36%19
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 280529504
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-E1-19-EC-30-E1-71-E7-F0-7A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::7e39:53ff:fec1:1b36%19
                                       195.121.1.34
                                       195.121.1.66
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I really can't make any sense out of the reason why certain devices seem unreachable for my desktop PC.

I tried to setup the access point in different "modes" (access point, brdige, client) but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Is this a familiar problem? Can somebody explain what is wrong? Can it be solved?

Comment: What is the output of `ipconfig /all` for the relevant interfaces on both machines? Please include that information in the original question and not a comment.

Comment: @acejavelin info added! I hope you can help me out

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, I'm not a network expert: is it possible, that your AP actually a wifi router? If it is, then (as far as I know) it can't work, because the software sends ARP packets to the LAN, to detect devices, but these packets (as far as I know) never go over the WAN interface of the router. 
Am I wrong?

Comment: heya, in any event thx a lot for the time to help me out. But if what you are saying was correct, how would that then explain that most of the devices ARE found, and only two (in my case an openelec linux PC and my NAS) are not?

Comment: other than that, I have setup my AP as "AP, bridge, and client". I don't know what that means internally, as I am not an access point expert or a network expert,  so I don't know if that still means that it uses stuff like routing / NAT etc.

Comment: +1 for your user name as it's just funny to read in this Q&A context :D

Comment: You're right, I was inattentive while read your post. :(
I assumed that your desktop see only devices on your AP.
Another idea: packet filter/firewall blocks some but not all of your devices on the NAS and the others? 
As I said, I'm not a network expert, so I have no more idea.